# When keypress is used without jtextfield, or jpasswordfield labels appear

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jpasswordfield

My keypress code

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        jLabel7.setVisible(true);            
        jLabel8.setVisible(true);
        jLabel9.setVisible(true); 
        jLabel10.setVisible(true);
        jLabel11.setVisible(true);
        myBlink();
    }
}
```

with myBlink() as

```
public void myBlink()
    {
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            boolean visible8 = true;
            boolean visible9 = true;
            boolean visible10 = true;
            boolean visible11 = true;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jLabel8.setEnabled(visible8 =  !visible8);                                
            jLabel9.setEnabled(visible9 = !visible9);
            jLabel10.setEnabled(visible10 = !visible10);
            jLabel11.setEnabled(visible11 = !visible11);
        }
    }).start();
    }
```

makes labels visible when key "A" is pressed.  If I place a jPasswordField or jTextField (see following adds to code of keypress) none of the labels in the keypress becomes visible.

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        jLabel7.setVisible(true);            
        jLabel8.setVisible(true);
        jLabel9.setVisible(true); 
        jLabel10.setVisible(true);
        jLabel11.setVisible(true);
        jPasswordField1.setVisible(true);
        myBlink();
    }
}
```

The passwordField or textField are set to visible(false) when jFrame opens.  Why should a passwordfield or textfield cause keypress to act differently than when another label is added.

Comment: Answer found in Unresponsive KeyListener for JFrame